# Send a data request with headers

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I'm using Twitter API v1.1. I've created a valid authorization header (using 0auth).

Now I want to actually send a request to Twitter for the data I want but I'm fairly new to PHP and certainly haven't got a damn clue about cURL.

So far I've got:

```
$authHeader = 'Authorization: 0Auth ....... Expect:'
$baseURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.$screenName.'&count='.$tweetCount;
```

Then I found the following code in twitterAPIexchange which I can't get working for me:

```
 $options = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $authHeader,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $baseURL,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
  );

  $feed = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
  $json = curl_exec($feed);
  curl_close($feed);
```

Can anyone help me with the header formation to make this request?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the headers as an array, e.g.

```
curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('HeaderName1: HeaderValue1', 'HeaderName2: HeaderValue2'));
```

Or, in your case,

```
$authHeader = array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key...');
$baseURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.$screenName.'&count='.$tweetCount;

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $authHeader,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $baseURL,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);
```

Comment: What exactly are you sending in the Authorization header? Can you give an example? (with gibberish data, ofc)